# Array inside of an Object inside of an Array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have the following source:

`let source = [{ name: "Player1",
                 cars:[{id: 20, count: 11}, {id: 23, count: 6}, {id: 2, count: 5}],
                 cars_total: 22
               },
               { name: "Player2",
                 cars:[{id: 11, count: 5}, {id: 24, count: 5}, {id: 42, count: 4}],
                 cars_total: 14
             }]`

Well .. i expect it is that kind of storage i want to use.
A player can have a several amount of cars (identified with its ID).
e.g.

Player1 has

- car-A (ID 20) 11 times
- car-B (ID 23) 6 times
- car-C (ID 2) 5 times

and so on ... I receive these information directly from a webpage using selectors.

What i want to do is to insert the information into this array above and then output it somewhere.

My try:

```
        intVehicleId = $('a').attr('vehicle_type_id');
        if(intVehicleId == "undefined") intVehicleId = null;           

        strProfileLinkText = $('a').children('a[href^="/profile/"]').text();

        if(!strProfileLinkText == 0) {
            intGetNamePos = -1;
            intGetCarPos = -1;

            for (var i = 0; i < arrNames.length; i++){
                if(arrNames[i].name == strProfileLinkText) {
                    intGetNamePos = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            intGetNamePos = -1;
            if(intGetNamePos > -1) {
                //if(arrNames[intGetNamePos].cars.length == 0) intGetCarPos = -1;
                //else intGetCarPos = $.each(arrNames[intGetNamePos].cars, function(idx2, val2) { if(val2.id == intVehicleId) return idx2; });

                //arrNames[intGetNamePos].cars_total++;

                for (var j = 0; j < arrNames[intGetNamePos].cars.length; j++){
                    //if(arrNames[intGetNamePos].cars[j].id == intVehicleId) intGetCarPos = j; break;
                }

                if(intGetCarPos > -1) {
                    //arrNames[intGetNamePos].cars[intGetCarPos].count++; arrNames[intGetNamePos].cars_total++;
                } else {
                    //arrNames[intGetNamePos].cars.push({id:intVehicleId, count:1}); arrNames[intGetNamePos].cars_total++;
                }
            } else {
                //arrNames.push({name:strProfileLinkText, cars:[{id:intVehicleId, count:1}], cars_total:1});

                intCarsId.id = 0; //intVehicleId
                intCarsId.count = 1;
                arrCars.push(intCarsId);

                strTemp.name = strProfileLinkText;
                strTemp.cars = arrCars;
                strTemp.cars_total = 1;
                console.log(strProfileLinkText);
                arrNames.push(strTemp);
            }
        }
    });
```

Now what happens is pretty weird. Sometimes

- nothing happens or
- instead of "22 cars by Player 1, 24 cars by Player 2" it writes "22 cars by Player 1, 24 cars by Player 1" or
- "1 cars by Player 1, 1 cars by Player 1, 1 cars by Player 1, 1 cars by Player 1, 1 cars by Player 1, 1 cars by Player 1, 1 cars by Player 1" and so on ...

I checked every single variable at every moment and everything seems fine. But not storing the information. Now i dont have any clue what i can do ...

Is that the right way to store my information? Or should i use several arrays and try to combine them when i need them?

Oh the comments show some other trys by me. E.g. via push and a try to combine cars of the same class to one row (and increment the count).

Im looking forward to find a solution with you guys :) despite this weird situation ... Ask if you need more information.

EDIT:

```
Input (later i replace the IDs with names):
ID 1 - Player 1
ID 1 - Player 2
ID 2 - Player 2
ID 3 - Player 3
ID 2 - Player 3
ID 1 - Player 2
ID 2 - Player 2

Expected output (of course in a table or whatever):
4x Player 2 | 3x ID 1, 1x ID 2
2x Player 3 | 1x ID 3, 1x ID 2
1x Player 1 | 1x ID 1
```

Comment: if you can Jquery then it becomes even more easier to parse into arrays by using `$.each` method. 

Just share the expected output by drawing sketch or writing in mspaint and let me write output code for you . @Gepu

Comment: "I receive these information directly from the code of the HTML", What does this mean? I am not sure if I understood your problem. Where are you getting the data from?

Comment: I receive the data from a webpage, selecting it from the code. '<div>ID1</div>' for example. Sorry quite bad language by me ...

Comment: @GePu. show me some sample input

Comment: I edited the post. Hopefully now for a better understanding :)

Comment: @GePu, Is the input a single string? like this, let input =  "ID 1 - Player 1
ID 1 - Player 2
ID 2 - Player 2
ID 3 - Player 3
ID 2 - Player 3
ID 1 - Player 2
ID 2 - Player 2"

Comment: @SatishKumar I know it is really hart to understand this :( It is a game where you are playing the central office of fire departments. You can send a car to e.g. an accident. I want to figure out how many cars are send by which player and what are those cars. Check this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ja2fvm

Comment: @SatishKumar Well no those information are provided via HTML. E.g: `<div><div id="playername">Player1</div><div id="vehicles" vehicle_id="1">Car A</div></div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169788/discussion-between-satish-kumar-and-gepu).

Comment: @SatishKumar great plan. im waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```js
const arrIDCars = ["Car A", "Car B", "Car C", "Car D", "Car E"];
const vehicleIdArr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1];
const strProfileLinkTextArr = ["p1", "p1", "p2", "p2", "p3", "p3", "p2", "p2", "p1", "p1", "p2", "p2", "p3", "p3", "p2", "p2"];

let output = {};
strProfileLinkTextArr.forEach((text, index) => {
    if (typeof output[text] == "undefined") {
        output[text] = {};
    }

    const vId = vehicleIdArr[index];

    if (typeof output[text][arrIDCars[vId - 1]] == "undefined") {
        output[text] = { ...output[text], [arrIDCars[vId - 1]]: 0 };
    }

    output[text][arrIDCars[vId - 1]]++;
});
console.log(output);
```

You can see the output object holds the count of all cars each person has.

So to see all available cars of a particular person do this,

```
output["person name"]
```

or

```
output.personName //(personName is a variable)
```

Hope this helps.